# WPF abstract generic UserControl with binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

**Information**
We're dealing with .NET 4.0, WPF and are trying to bind some data to a generic abstract base class.
The classes we have are shown below. Each of these classes also has a public parameterless constructor, though I left them out in this post. Also note that **all the properties** in the classes have their setter extended to encapsulate the **PropertyChanged** event. These are also left out to make it more readable here.

**Settings classes**

```cs
public abstract class BaseSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class SomeSettings : BaseSettings
{
    // SomeOtherSettings : BaseSettings
    public SomeOtherSettings OTHER { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class SomeOtherSettings : BaseSettings
{
    public string X { get; set; }
}
```

**UserControl**

```cs
public abstract class BaseControl<S> : UserControl
    where S : BaseSettings, new()
{
    public S Settings
    {
        get { return (S)GetValue(SettingsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SettingsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SettingsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Settings", typeof(S), typeof(BaseControl<S>), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

```cs
public partial class MyControl : BaseControl<SomeOtherSettings>
{
}
```

```xml
<m:BaseControl x:Class=ProperClassPathHere
               x:TypeArguments=s:SomeSettings
               xmlns:s=ProperClassPathToSomeSettingsHere />

    <TextBox Text={Binding Settings.X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} />

</m:BaseControl>
```

**MainWindow**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SomeSettings SomeSettings { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class=ProperClassPathHere />

   <u:MyControl Settings={Binding Settings.OTHER} />

</Window>
```

**The issue**
We are able to bind the Settings.OTHER in the MainWindow, but the DataContext of the MyControl should be different from the MainWindow's. Due to this, we'll never see the value of X in the textbox...

Also Note:

- Since there is an abstract parent class, we cannot use the x:Name property here
- If we set the DateContext on the MyControl ourselves, the MainWindow cannot bind the Settings.OTHER anymore.

What are we missing here? Is there even a solution to this problem? Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: generics don't belong into the UI. Use proper DataTemplates instead.

Comment: That's a rather harsh statement... First, there is no argumentation. Second, given that we have to show quite some settings, each extending the BaseSettings, it would - according to basic object oriented programming - fulfil the once-and-only-once principle. You're basically saying we need to create dozens of UserControls, each holding it's own property (and other methods)? Or rather create no UserControls at all and create a MainWindow that no-one would like to scroll through..?

Comment: I can't really tell exactly what you're asking. "the DataContext of the MyControl should be different from the MainWindow's." What do you want the DataContext of the MyControl to be? Whatever you want it to be, set it to that.

`<u:MyControl DataContext={Binding ...} />`